# How can I archive my cocoa framework

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, release, archive

Sorry for my poor English first.I have a problem and I googled it and try to solve this problem the whole day.

The problem is I have a cocoa framework project, and It build succeeded and archive succeeded.
BUT when my project using this framework, it will show can't find the framework, image not found.

OK, I know the problem now, so I searched and find out @executable_path and @loader_path, to make the project using this framework will find the path easy.

But when I change install directory in Building Settings from the default value ~/Library/Framework to @executable_path/../Framework, my framework STILL could build success and archive success.But I can't find the archive file and archive window will not show.Xcode tells me below:

Check dependencies

Warning: Installation Directory starts with @executable_path but Skip Install is disabled.

TIPS:

When I set @executable_path, Xcode tells me "The skip install to YES", I can't do that, because when I set to YES, it won't archive for me.

**How could I solve this problem? Or anything wrong in my project?**

Thanks so much!

My code here https://github.com/GuoJing/DoubanAPICocoa

Answer (score 0):

you need to use loader path to identify the framework path